# Python: How to remove default options on Typer CLI?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, typer

I made a simple CLI using [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to change image opacity and this program only have one option: opacity.

But when I run `python opacity.py --help` it gives me the two typerCLI options:

```sh
Options:
  --install-completion [bash|zsh|fish|powershell|pwsh]
                                  Install completion for the specified
                                  shell.

  --show-completion [bash|zsh|fish|powershell|pwsh]
                                  Show completion for the specified
                                  shell, to copy it or customize the
                                  installation.

  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

There's a way to disable it? I didn't find on docs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I met the same problem today, i couldn't find anything except this question so dived in the source to find how Typer automatically adds this line in app, so i found this, when **Typer** initialiazing itself it automatically sets `add_completion` to True

```
class Typer:
    def __init__(add_completion: bool = True)
```

So when you initialiazing your app you can add this

```
app = typer.Typer(add_completion=False)
```

This is how it looks after you add `add_completion=False`

```
Usage: main.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version `0.7.0`, Typer now [excludes these by default](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/releases/tag/0.7.0) if you use the `typer.run()` API.

Example:

```python
# foo.py
import typer

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

Produces:

```bash
$ pip install typer[all]==0.7.0
$ python foo.py --help

 Usage: foo.py [OPTIONS]

╭─ Options ───────────────────────────────────────╮
│ --help          Show this message and exit.     │
╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```